# Clicking a checkbox using protractor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, protractor

There is no unique model, id, label names. How am I suppose to check/click the checkboxes?

The html/code is:

```
<div ng-repeat="column in $parent.columns.standardMetrics" class="ng-scope">
      <label class="ng-binding">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.visible" name="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        uCPM
      </label>
    </div>

</div><div ng-repeat="column in $parent.columns.standardMetrics" class="ng-scope">
      <label class="ng-binding">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.visible" name="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        CPM
      </label>
    </div>
```

There is about 15 of these with the same name besides the label next to the name. I searched everywhere to see if protractor allows you to find elements by label.

My attempts are finding via by.buttonText, by.partialButtonText, by.css and by.binding. I have no luck on this.

My purpose is to pass in a label name that I can toggle the specific checkbox.
So it's like `element(by.css(header)).click();` 
where header is what is passed in.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using ids. Use a directive to add ids to each checkbox, then you can something like this:

```
element(by.css('input[myid="checkbox_x"]')); // where x is defined in a loop
```

Comment: There isn't any id. What you see in my question is the exact code.

Comment: I can't add id's, this website isn't mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `by.xpath()`:

```
element(by.xpath('//input[@ng-model = "column.visible" and following-sibling::text() = "' + label + '"]'));
```

Comment: So it will be 

`element(by.xpath('//input[' +header+ '= "' + label '"]')) ` ?

Comment: @wtosh just realized that you should be checking the following sibling text. Check the update. Example value of the label would be `uCPM` or `CPM`.

Comment: Where would my passed in variable go?

Comment: @wtosh label is the variable here.

Comment: Copy and pasted and replaced "label" with header but gave me an error:
Unexpected string
Puts to the `'"]'))` at the code.

Comment: @wtosh oops, that was an error - missed the +, check it out.

Comment: How do I combine it to click the checkbox?

Comment: @wtosh just add `click()` this way: `element(by.xpath('//input[following-sibling::text() = "' + label + '"]')).click();`.

Comment: Got the error:
ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted.

It's on the screen when I run it.

Comment: I also tried `element.all(by.xpath('//input[following-sibling::text() = "' + header + '"]')).click();`

Comment: Oh, you mean the newest edited code, just tried it, it couldn't find the element.
`"NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.xpath("//input[@ng-model =\"column.visible\" and following-sibling::text() = \"uCPM\""]"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there will be better answer out there. I just started learning protractor :) You can try clicking on it by index.

3 = position.

```
element.all(by.repeater('column in $parent.columns.standardMetrics').get(3).element(by.css('[ng-model="column.visible"]')).click();
```

Comment: How would I find the exact index of the variable I am passing in?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: missed that the text belonged to the label and not the input.

This should work:
element(by.xpath("//label[text()='uCPM']/input"));

Answer (score 0):

Assign a dinamic id to the elements:

```
<div ng-repeat="column in $parent.columns.standardMetrics" class="ng-scope">
      <label id="label{{$index}}" class="ng-binding">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.visible" name="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        uCPM
      </label>
</div>
```

Then on protractor:

```
element(by.id('label0')).click();
```

p.s. Just read that you can't change HTML because the website is not yours. Try this:

```
var first= element.all(by.repeater('column in $parent.columns.standardMetrics')).get(0);
first.get(0).then(function(el) {
  el.click();
});
```